# Bridge does not get IP via DHCP at boot

Tags: centos, dhcp, bridge

I'm running CentOS 7. I'm not running NetworkManager, and I've actually uninstalled it.

My system is supposed to acquire an IPv4 address via DHCP on `br0` at boot. Howver, when I log in, it has no address.

My configuration:

```
# pwd
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts

# cat ifcfg-enp5s0 
DEVICE=enp5s0
ONBOOT="yes"
BRIDGE=br0

# cat ifcfg-br0 
DEVICE=br0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
STP=on
DELAY=0
```

Note that I didn't configure this bridge manually; `virt-manager` did so when I added `br0` on this dialog:

[image: virt-manager screenshot showing br0 on Network Interfaces tab]

Relevant `journalctl --boot | grep  '\(\<br0\>\|enp5s0\)'` and context:

```
Jan 08 21:04:32 jonathon-centos7 kernel: r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link down
Jan 08 21:04:32 jonathon-centos7 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp5s0: link is not ready
Jan 08 21:04:32 jonathon-centos7 kernel: r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link down
Jan 08 21:04:32 jonathon-centos7 kernel: device enp5s0 entered promiscuous mode
Jan 08 21:04:32 jonathon-centos7 network[947]: Bringing up interface enp5s0:  [  OK  ]
...
Jan 08 21:04:32 jonathon-centos7 network[947]: Bringing up interface br0:
Jan 08 21:04:32 jonathon-centos7 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br0: link is not ready
...
Jan 08 21:04:34 jonathon-centos7 kernel: r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link up
Jan 08 21:04:34 jonathon-centos7 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp5s0: link becomes ready
Jan 08 21:04:34 jonathon-centos7 kernel: br0: port 1(enp5s0) entered listening state
Jan 08 21:04:34 jonathon-centos7 kernel: br0: port 1(enp5s0) entered listening state
//// (Note: 2 second delay here, with no other events)
Jan 08 21:04:36 jonathon-centos7 avahi-daemon[957]: Registering new address record for fe80::f66d:4ff:fe3b:c24e on enp5s0.*.
Jan 08 21:04:36 jonathon-centos7 kernel: br0: port 1(enp5s0) entered learning state
///// (Too soon!)
Jan 08 21:04:38 jonathon-centos7 network[947]: Determining IP information for br0... failed; no link present.  Check cable?
Jan 08 21:04:38 jonathon-centos7 network[947]: [FAILED]
Jan 08 21:04:38 jonathon-centos7 systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 08 21:04:38 jonathon-centos7 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Jan 08 21:04:38 jonathon-centos7 systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
...
Jan 08 21:04:38 jonathon-centos7 kernel: br0: topology change detected, propagating
Jan 08 21:04:38 jonathon-centos7 kernel: br0: port 1(enp5s0) entered forwarding state
Jan 08 21:04:38 jonathon-centos7 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br0: link becomes ready
Jan 08 21:04:39 jonathon-centos7 avahi-daemon[957]: Registering new address record for fe80::f66d:4ff:fe3b:c24e on br0.*.
Jan 08 21:04:41 jonathon-centos7 avahi-daemon[957]: Registering new address record for 2605:a000:1315:8119:f66d:4ff:fe3b:c24e on br0.*.
Jan 08 21:04:41 jonathon-centos7 avahi-daemon[957]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::f66d:4ff:fe3b:c24e on br0.

///// (Here's where I entered `ifup br0`)
Jan 08 22:43:30 jonathon-centos7 dhclient[5009]: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x25f649b7)
Jan 08 22:43:31 jonathon-centos7 dhclient[5009]: DHCPREQUEST on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x25f649b7)
Jan 08 22:43:34 jonathon-centos7 avahi-daemon[957]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface br0.IPv4 with address 10.0.1.128.
Jan 08 22:43:34 jonathon-centos7 avahi-daemon[957]: New relevant interface br0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 08 22:43:34 jonathon-centos7 avahi-daemon[957]: Registering new address record for 10.0.1.128 on br0.IPv4.
Jan 08 23:43:17 jonathon-centos7 dhclient[5124]: DHCPREQUEST on br0 to 10.0.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x25f649b7)
```

After the system boots, and I'm logged-in, I can open a terminal, and:

```
# ifup br0
set forward delay failed: Numerical result out of range

Determining IP information for br0... done.
```

And then I'm connected to my network.

**Why am I unable to get an IP for `br0` at boot?**

Related:

- [Ethernet bridge with dhcp](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39494) [CentOS forms]

Notes:

- `brctl showstp br0` shows that the forward delay is set to 2.00. `brctl setfd br0 0` shows the same error as `ifup br0`. It seems that virt-manager specified an invalid `DELAY=0` for `br0`.
- **After finding the important entries in the logs, it seems that `systemd` is trying to get an IP for`br0` before it has entered the forwarding state.**
- I've opened [bug 8086](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8086) on the CentOS bugtracker.

Comment: *Update*: Removing `STP=yes` from my config allows me to win this race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your bridge is not being controlled by the network initscripts, it's being controlled by libvirt. The bridge should come up when the libvirtd service comes up.

I would not run like this. I would make the bridge controlled by the network initscript, and have no bridge in the libvirt configuration.

The ifcfg- files you have now are fine. Just remove the config from libvirt, ensure you still have those files, then `chkconfig network on`

Yes, chkconfig works on EL7.

Comment: *"Just remove the config from libvirt,"* How do I do this? Any why was virt-manager able to so easily create such a broken setup?

Answer (score 1):

A quote from http://www.microhowto.info/howto/persistently_bridge_traffic_between_two_or_more_ethernet_interfaces_on_redhat.html:

> For this reason you may want to leave STP disabled in simple cases (such as when bridging a set of virtual machines to a single physical interface)

Disabling STP seems to be the way to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Your physical link is not up when your bridge starts. Add a delay to your physical interface.